# find returns empty matrix

Tags: matlab, find, is-empty

I have two vectors which are of length 200,000 approximately. They consist of dates in the datenum format.

```
%datenums
date_exp = datenum(data_exp(:,1:6));
date_sim = datenum(data_sim(:,1:6));
```

1. I want to find the dates in date_exp that exists in date_sim.
2. Then remove the values from date_exp

I have used the the ismember tool but ending up at i=38 find retunrs: Improper assignment with rectangular empty matrix.

> Error in filter (line 18)
>       c(i)= find(ismember(date_sim(:),date_exp(i)),1);

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
c = zeros(length(date_sim),1);

for i=1:length(date_sim)

c(i)= find(ismember(date_sim(:),date_exp(i)),1);

    if isempty(c(i)) == 1
    c(i) = 0; 
    end
end 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

I would be really helpful if anyone could help me out here.

Comment: if `find` returns an empty matrix it means that there are no true values. `date_exp(38)` is not in `date_sim`. Also instead of `find` you can use `[~, c(i)] = ismember(date_exp(i), date_sim);`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because `date_exp(38)` must not be within `date_sim`. When there are no 1's in the input, `find` returns an empty array (`[]`).

Your code does not handle this as you would expect though because of this line.

```
c(i) = find(...)
```

In this case, if there are no matches (`find() == []`), then you are essentially calling

```
c(i) = [];
```

**This deletes the ith element of `c` element**

Therefore the following line is never true!

```
if isempty(c(i)) == 1
```

Instead, you should probably do something to handle the empty value.

```
index = find(ismember(date_sim(:), date_exp(i)), 1);

%// Only assign the index if it isn't an empty array
if ~isempty(index)
    c(i) = index;
end
```

You don't have to worry about assigning zeros because your initial matrix is *already* full of zeros.

## A Better Option

All of that aside, it would likely be a much better approach to not loop at all and to instead use the [second output](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html#outputarg_Locb)  of [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) (on the arrays before you pass them to `datenum`) to give you the same result in a *much* more efficient way.

```
[~, c] = ismember(date_exp(:,1:6), date_sim(:,1:6), 'rows');
```